# xUnit Tests not running after building

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

I'm trying to run unit tests in VisualStudio 2013. My tests are discovered under the Test Explorer but after running the tests, the project builds and stops. All my tests are then categorised under "Not Run".
I'm not getting any error messages or exceptions.

Comment: Are there any test result files somewhere in your project directory?

Comment: Use Test -> Debug All and verify that it doesn't throw any exceptions. Also take a look at the Tests output pane and the statusbar when running.

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of .vsp files.

Comment: While you are doing what @JeroenVannevel suggested, press `Ctrl + Alt + E`, and check "thrown" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This will let you see exceptions you would otherwise not be aware of.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel & gunr2171: I've done that and the coast looks pretty clear on the Debug console, the only thing close to an error is " Cannot find or open the PDB file" which appears at the end of a good number of lines in the console.

Comment: @TechHands, Are you building the project the tests are referencing? Are there .pdb files in that project's bin directory?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jeroen Vannel & gunr2171.

I fixed it by installing `xunit.runner` to the test project from the NuGet Manager instead of running the installation of the `xunit.runner` Visual Studio Extension file I downloaded previously.